# How to define design rules for Java classes?

Tags: java, oop

I want to define some design rules for a medium-size project developing by a team. These rules aren't like "`if` statements must use brackets" rule. They are related to design desicions.

Example rules:

- If a class has an association with a JPA class, it should not have any association with a GUI class.
- For each subclass of `Message`, there should be a subclass of `Serializer`.
- If a class marked as DTO, it should have only getter and setter methods.

Is there a way to define rules like example ones and check them compile time?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java. Sounds like you want something like CheckStyle.

Comment: I don't try that tool. But I want to check design with custom rules not only style.

Comment: if you have nails and screws, you need a hammer *and* a screwdriver. By which I mean to say... why not use more than 1 tool, if each tool is best suited to just 1 of your requirements?

Comment: Interesting question; but **way** too broad and definitely about "opinionated" answers in the first place. In that sense: you should start by studying the existing tools (as for example: checkstyle is much more than just checking "style").

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to design some compile time processed annotations. And design a very clever annotation processor.

Never the less this will not be an easy task and maybe you want to write them down instead of hardcode them. But if you want to go that way here are some suggestions for your examples:

- Create a `@IsJPA` annotation that must be used with any of your JPA associated class.
  Create a `@IsGUI` annotation that must be used with any of your GUI classes.
  In the annotation processor scan every `@IsJPA` annotated class for references to `@IsGUI` annotated class.
- Create a `@IsMessage` annotation and in annotation processor check that these classes are subclasses of `Serializer`
- Create a `@IsDTO` annotation and and in annotation processor check that these classes only have getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this point:

> If a class has an association with a JPA class, it should not have any association with a GUI class.

I would recommend defining which dependencies are allowed between packages. You can do this and check it at compile time with a free tool like [classycle](http://classycle.sourceforge.net/) or a commercial tool like [structure101](https://structure101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In Sonar, you could define your custom rules.

that's a bit of code to write, but I think you could do want you want.

[Writing Custom Java Rules 101](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)

Then Sonarqube analysis could be run with Jenkins and Maven.
Or it could be checked in real-time during the development, using the plugin SonarLint (for Eclipse or Intelli-J).

And Sonar is free and easy to configure. (but for implementing custom rules, it will depend of the rules complexity)